# How to initialize one more property in composite id

Tags: java, hibernate

Have the following:

```
<class name="ClassName" entity-name="EntityName1" table="table1" lazy="false">

    <composite-id name="classPK" class="com.....ClassPK">
        <key-property name="ID" column="id" type="integer"/>
    </composite-id>
.....
```

and

```
    <class name="ClassName" entity-name="EntityName2" table="table2" lazy="false">

    <composite-id name="classPK" class="com.....ClassPK">
        <key-property name="ID" column="id" type="integer"/>
    </composite-id>
.....
```

i.e. 2 entities that maps to 2 tables but with the same class. Composite ID is used like im code above. What is need it to initialize one more property in ClassPK class when entity EntityName2 or EntityName1 is loaded from DB. I need to initialize it by 2 different constant values. For example "value1" and value2 for EntityName1 and EntityName2 respectivly.

So I would like to have a possibility ti write something like

```
<class name="ClassName" entity-name="EntityName1" table="table" lazy="false">

<composite-id name="classPK" class="com.....ClassPK">
    <key-property name="ID" column="id" type="integer"/>
    <property name="propertyname" formula = "'value1'"/>
</composite-id>
```

Does anybody have an idea how to do this?

Answer (score 0):

not sure if this is a good idea altogether but you coud try

```
<key-property name="propertyname" formula = "'value1'">
  <column formula="'value1'"/>
</key-property>
```